# Old project creation dialog in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How do I switch back to old project creation dialog in visual studio 2019,

the old project creation dialog:

[image]

Comment: I assume it’s not available. Should post on Connect, unless someone has already done it. The new one is definitely much worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bring back old project creation dialog using this extension and now that android version dropdown is available:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/3221

[image]

**Classic 'New Project' Dialog**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softworkz.SwitchProjectDialog

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option.

Visual Studio 2019 (like previous versions) has a single inbuilt way to create projects.